# A global shortcut to refresh the current window/tab in chrome

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, automator, system-preferences

Whilst programming a simple web site, I'm a bit annoyed by the need to switch from my code editor to chrome in order to refresh the page after each modification save.

Is there a way to assign a global shortcut to refresh the current window/tab of chrome?

Answer (score 2):

## Automator

- Open *Automator* and choose a  <kbd>New Document</kbd>
- Choose <kbd>Service</kbd>

[image: A screengrab showing the document type dialog in Automator]

- Set *Service receives* to <kbd>no input</kbd>
- Choose <kbd>Run AppleScript</kbd> action from the action list.
- Paste the following code in the script:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell the active tab of its first window
reload
end tell
```

[image: A screengrab showing the automator window actions]

- Save the the service, for example, using the name <kbd>Chrome Refresh</kbd>

## System Preferences

- Open *System Preferences* > *Keyboard*
- In the *Shortcuts* tab, choose <kbd>Services</kbd>
- Assign a new shortcut

[image: A screengrab showing System Preferences keyboard shortcut tab]

Comment: Any idea how to make it work in Catalina? `Google Chrome got an error: Can’t get window 1.`