# Use Automator to refresh a page in Chrome if its domain matches a given domain

Tags: google-chrome, applescript, automator

I found a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/745166/a-global-shortcut-to-refresh-the-current-window-tab-in-chrome/745167#745167) which explains how to use the Automator for Mac to create a service that will refresh the active tab in chrome.

I would like to make a similar service except that I don't want to just refresh the active tab.  I want to refresh a tab given its domain matches "mydomain.dev" for example.

Is this something I can do with an apple script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This AppleScript code should work for you.  It works for me running the latest version of Sierra.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to reload (tabs of window 1 whose URL contains "mydomain.dev")
```

Comment: If you put the above file contents in a `reload-chrome.scpt` file then you can run it from the command line with `osascript reload-chrome.scpt`